# Combining groups in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a query that groups by the field description. (There are 9 total descriptions.) I need to somehow combine 3 of these descriptions into one group, giving me a total of 7 descriptions. I'm brand new to sql querying, so I'm fairly lost on anything beyond JOINS and WHERE clauses so far. I appreciate the help.

```
SELECT        serviceclass.description, DATEPART(Year, meterread.readdate) AS Year, DATEPART(Month, meterread.readdate) AS Month, SUM(meterread.consumption) 
                     AS Consumption, COUNT(DISTINCT accountservice.account_id) AS Locations
FROM            accountservice INNER JOIN
                     serviceclass ON accountservice.serviceclass_id = serviceclass.serviceclass_id INNER JOIN
                     meterread ON accountservice.accountservice_id = meterread.accountservice_id
WHERE        (@Year = DATEPART(Year, meterread.readdate))
GROUP BY serviceclass.description, DATEPART(Year, meterread.readdate), DATEPART(Month,meterread.readdate)
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

Comment: Provide the sample descriptions and how do you want to group those 3 you are interested in grouping.

Comment: Will you always want the same three descriptions grouped together, or can that set of 3 vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `CASE` statement.

replace `serviceclass.desription` in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses with

```
CASE
    WHEN serviceclass.description IN ('Desc1','Desc2','Desc3')
        THEN 'JointDescription'
    ELSE serviceclass.description
END
```

and also update the Desc 1 ~ 3 with your three description and updated the joint description to what you want it to be.

RESULT:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN serviceclass.description IN ('Desc1','Desc2','Desc3')
               THEN 'JointDescription'
           ELSE serviceclass.description
       END as description, 
       DATEPART(Year, meterread.readdate) AS Year,  
       DATEPART(Month, meterread.readdate) AS Month, 
       SUM(meterread.consumption) AS Consumption, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT accountservice.account_id) AS Locations
FROM accountservice 
INNER JOIN serviceclass ON accountservice.serviceclass_id = serviceclass.serviceclass_id 
INNER JOIN meterread ON accountservice.accountservice_id = meterread.accountservice_id
WHERE        (@Year = DATEPART(Year, meterread.readdate))
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN serviceclass.description IN ('Desc1','Desc2','Desc3')
                  THEN 'JointDescription'
             ELSE serviceclass.description
         END, 
         DATEPART(Year, meterread.readdate), 
         DATEPART(Month,meterread.readdate)
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically do this with a `case` statement that would go in both the `select` and `group by` statements.  Something like:

```
select (case when serviceclass.description = 'A' then 'B'
             else serviceclass.description
        end) as description
       . . . -- fill in with query here
group by (case when serviceclass.description = 'A' then 'B'
             else serviceclass.description
           end), . . .  -- rest of query goes here
```